# How do I use numpy's polyfit when applied to two lists?

Tags: python, numpy

```
y_boxes_1 = [y[i:i + divisor_1] for i in range(0, len(y), divisor_1)]
x_boxes_1 = [x[i:i + divisor_1] for i in range(0, len(x), divisor_1)]
```

The above code divides a list by a divisor. What I want to do is use numpy polyfit to create a new list of polynomial coefficients for each individual box of y and box of x.

If:

```
x_boxes_1 = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]] 
y_boxes_1 = [[3,5,2,3,1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,1,5,6,7,10]]
```

Then polyfit would use only the values from x_boxes_1[0] and y_boxes_1[0] and x_boxes_1[1] and y_boxes_1[1] and produce a new list with the coefficients from each individual calculation.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Downvoted in less then 2 minutes. Is there something wrong with my post?

Comment: What is your question? Check out [ask] for tips on how to improve your question.

Comment: I thought it was obvious, but nonetheless I have edited.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're trying to fit.  Are each "box" dependent or independent of each other?  That matters.

Comment: Thank you. I will try and be more clear in the future (new member). Yes the boxes are independent of eachother.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand `x_boxes_1` holds the coordinates, and `y_boxes_1` holds the points that you want to fit a polynomial. And, you want to call `polyfit` two times for each corresponding pair. If that is the case, this should work:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_boxes_1 = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]] 
y_boxes_1 = [[3,5,2,3,1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,1,5,6,7,10]] 

zipped = zip(x_boxes_1, y_boxes_1)

z_boxes_1 = [np.polyfit(x,y,6) for x,y in zipped]
```

Note that degree of the fitting polynomial is 6.

You can plot to verify:

```
xp_boxes_1 = [np.linspace(1, 8, 100), np.linspace(9, 16, 100)]
for i in [0,1]:
    x = x_boxes_1[i]
    y = y_boxes_1[i]
    z = z_boxex_1[i]
    xp = xp_boxes_1[i]
    p = np.poly1d(z)
    plt.subplot(1,2,i+1)
    plt.plot(x, y, '.', xp, p(xp), '-');
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. That is exactly what I was looking for! I am new to python and i never knew about the zip function!